# Required id field(s) not found in record JSON POST REST API Dreamfactory

Tags: sql-server, json, rest, post, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to POST some test JSON data to a MS SQLServer database via REST Api hosted by Dreamfactory and I get an Error:

`"message": "Required id field(s) not found in record 0: Array\n(\n    [AdID] =&gt; 1\n    [DateTime] =&gt; 8/22/14\n    [ClickedBool] =&gt; 1\n)\n",
      "code": 400`

I have the database configured to autoincrement the ID, I believe:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdViews] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[AdID]        INT            NOT NULL,
[DateTime]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[ClickedBool] TINYINT        NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And when I try to post the data with an ID, it has a SQL error because it is not allowed to explicitly give an Id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I had to have at least one record in the table before I could post, apparently it needs a record to compare so it can auto-increment the next ID number.  The database table was empty when I tried the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your JSON request?

This [link](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/SQL-Database-Services) in the documentation is helpful

```
Types

id : defines a typical table identifier, translates to "int not null auto_increment primary key".
```

Not recommended, but if all else fails, you can allow inserts into Identity column.
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ADVIEWS ON

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs.  Ok I found that it is defined as an ID and that it is set to autoincrement in Dreamfactory settings.